# Disable dates older than today with datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I'm trying to figure out how to disable all the dates older than today, this gets tricky with the bootstrap datetime picker I am using below.

The examples allows for an array of dates to be passed when creating the object :

```
$(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
                    defaultDate: "11/1/2013",
                    disabledDates: [
                        moment("12/25/2013"),
                        new Date(2013, 11 - 1, 21),
                        "11/22/2013 00:53"
                    ]
                });
            });
```

How can I do this without calculating all the dates before today and passing that to the function ?

**Doc** : http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#example8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you looked for a bad option....

**Doc** : Look at here : http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#options

In this doc, the option's name is `minDate`

**Extract** :

```
    minuteStepping:1,               //set the minute stepping
    minDate:`1/1/1900`,               //set a minimum date  <---- HERE 
    maxDate: ,
```

Answer (score 3):

```
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
                defaultDate: moment("11/01/2013", "DD-MM-YYYY"),
                minDate: moment()
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from setting the `minDate` property, you might also want to disable *times* before the current time. You would do this as follows:

First, you need to initialise the `minDate` parameter to midnight of the current day. Then, you bind an event listener to the `dp.change` event and reject any times that are *earlier* than the current time.
When rejecting such a time, you notify the user and reset the DateTimePicker time to the current time. I've created a function to do this:

```
// Argument obj is the used DateTimePicker object
// Argument f is the selected datetime by the user
// Argument n is the current datetime
var checkDate = function (obj, f, n) {
    if (f.getTime() < n.getTime()+60*1000 && !open) {
        open = true;
        $('#message').dialog({
            modal: true,
            position: ['center', 'center'],
            show: 'blind',
            hide: 'blind',
            width: 400,
            dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
            buttons: {
                "I understand. Let me try again": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    obj.data('DateTimePicker').setDate(n);
                    open = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Likewise, you still want to update the `minDate` and `maxDate` parameters upon `dp.change` too. Therefore, combining both checking the time and updating the properties, you would get:

```
jQuery("#startDate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    var f = new Date(e.date);    var n = new Date();
    checkDate(jQuery('#startDate'), f, n);
    jQuery('#endDate').data("DateTimePicker").setMinDate(e.date);
});
jQuery("#endDate").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    var f = new Date(e.date);    var n = new Date();
    checkDate(jQuery('#startDate'), f, n);
    jQuery('#startDate').data("DateTimePicker").setMaxDate(e.date);
});
```

This will yield exactly what you are after:

[image]

You can find the full code in the jsFiddle I prepared for you:

## [GO TO THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fca4x889/)